# Is it preferable to retrieve information directly from one site or through my web server using php?

Tags: php, android, webserver, jsoup

I have an application that retrieves some info and give them to user from a certain public website. However, i am not sure whether i should let my app immediately connect to the target website or it should get the info through my web server using a simple `PHP` script (`JSON`). 
Actually I am using `Jsoup` to get the information and I tried both and they worked perfectly ( immediate and PHP) using `Jsoup`. However, I have not published my app yet due to the confusion aforementioned.

Answer (score 1):

Use the web service. If your client has logic to parse the HTML, it can break when the web page changes. The web service can absorb this change and make corrections, but your client cannot. Not unless you release another version of your app, and that can be a pain.

Comment: i just didn't want too many traffic on my web server, this is why i'm asking.. how can I know how much traffic does my web server bear?

Comment: Use an estimation technique. Averge users * calls per user = load on server. Give yourself a 40% buffer for peak loads. Cache the HTML response to reduce the load on the server even more.

Comment: Interesting. What do you mean by 40% buffer for peak load? Plus I have no idea about caching HTML responses, should I place a certain piece of code inside my php? or modify the php.ini or something like that?

Comment: Your site traffic can increase suddenly. Allow a 40% error in your estimates to cover this. The web service need not make the HTTP call to get the HTML each time. If you cache the response (say using a dictionary / memcache / redis ), the response time from the service will be faster.